# ping Minimum Interval?

Tags: networking, ping, icmp

No, not the 0.2s available to unprivileged users.

What is the minimum interval that ping (from iputils s20190709) supports?
I asked it to :

```
ping -s 18 -W 2 -w 300 -qOni 0.000024
```

... but it seems to cap out around ~1,200 PPS (723139 packets / 600s) :

```
723139 packets transmitted, 723072 received, 0.00926516% packet loss, time 600000ms 
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.463/0.750/26.080/0.249 ms, pipe 2, ipg/ewma 0.829/0.714 ms
```

By my calculation, requesting 18 bytes (total 60 bytes "on the wire" over Ethernet) @ ~42,000PPS (1s / 0.000024 interval) should generate only ~20Mbps traffic - not nearly too much for a 1Gbps path.

I tried a flood to the same remote host ...

```
ping -n -w 60 -W 2 -s 18 -f
```

... which is supposed to "outputs packets as fast as they come back or one hundred times per second, whichever is more" and results were :

```
73338 packets transmitted, 73320 received, 0.0245439% packet loss, time 59999ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.428/0.728/16.213/0.218 ms, pipe 2, ipg/ewma 0.818/0.740 ms
```

Or ~1,222 PPS.
At least this result is expected given the description of the -f flag.
(Tried without the -W option in case that influences it - same outcome.)

Pinging loopback yielded ~107,494 PPS :

```
ping -s 18 -W 2 -w 60 -qOnf 127.0.0.1
```

```
6449594 packets transmitted, 6449594 received, 0% packet loss, time 60000ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.005/0.005/0.709/0.001 ms, ipg/ewma 0.009/0.006 ms
```

... so I assume that ping does not have a hard-coded minimum interval (certainly not near ~1,200 PPS).
I assume that my ~1,200PPS is because ping is waiting for N echo replies before fire off the next request within the interval, whether using -f or -i ?

How can I ask ping to either :

1. Flood with no limit (neither 100 times / sec, nor "fast as they come back") ?
2. Honour the requested -i interval in non-flood mode, regardless of responses received ?

If ping can't do this, can fping/oping/nping ?
Will try running multiple ping processes in parallel ...

I am using Ubuntu.

Comment: Obvs still curious about this, but in the meantime iperf3 might do what I need (honour interval without regard for response loss or RTT) : iperf3 -O 2 -P 1 -u -w 128K -b 2M -t 10 -l 18 -c x.x.x.x

Comment: It is not clear what your end goal is. To me `mtr` is a god sent for network debugging, and even if it does not solve your issue here, you should have it in your toolbox.